# Testing behavior of activity when destroying

Tags: android, android-espresso

I have class which have reference to the Activity and Resource:

```
public class MainActivityController {
        private MainActivity mainActivity;
        private Resources resources;

        MainActivityController(MainActivity mainActivity, Resources resources)
        {
            this.mainActivity = mainActivity;
            this.resources = resources;
        }

        void onDestroy() {
            mainActivity = null;
            resources = null;
        }

        Object getMainActivity() {
            return mainActivity;
        }

        Resources getResources() {
            return resources;
        }

        public void onHelloButtonClicked() {
            mainActivity.displayMessage(resources.getString(R.string.hello_message));
        }
```

the method `onDestroy` is invoking when Activity destroyed:

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mainActivityController.onDestroy();
}
```

I would like to test if method `onDestroy` from MainActivityController was invoked and clear all references when activity destroyed

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
    @LargeTest
    public class MainActivityInstrumentalTest{
        @Rule
        public ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> mainActivityTestRule = new ActivityTestRule<MainActivity>(MainActivity.class);


        @Test
        public void shouldDestroyMainActivityControllerWhenActivityDestroyed()
        {
            //TODO: check if onDestroy was invoked when activity destroyed
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert of testing but i think it is not your job to test android frameworks methods. Let it to google ingeneers.
And activity lifecycle methods are part of it.
Consider it is working.
You'd better focus on testing what you own. Like unit testing `mainActivityController.onDestroy();`

Comment: I don't want to test android methods. I already created unit test for mainActivityController.onDestroy(). Now I want to check if mainActivityController.onDestroy() was invoked when activity was destroyed and prevent from remove this part of code from MainActivity.onDestroy()